# How to change database timezone from UTC to local in wordpress

Tags: mysql, datetime, wordpress, timezone

I'm using a custom plugin in wordpress. All date and time are stored in database as UTC. I saw in `posts` table, there're **2 columns** for UTC and local timezone (post_date, post_date_gtm), but in this plugin table, there's only **1 column** to store the created date as UTC.

Currently, I'm using sql query and $wpdb to show the data between "start date" and "end date".
Please help me to show them in local timezone (That is setted in general setting) instead of UTC!

Thanks and sorry about my English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume your local time zone is `+05:00`, use the following condition:

```
WHERE CONVERT_TZ(col_date_utc, '+00:00', '+05:00') BETWEEN '....' AND '....'
```

Comment: Thank you! I have a small question:I use gtm_offset and it return for exp: -7.5, How can I convert this to -07:30, is there any function in wordpress support this?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Admin> Settings> Timezone?

Answer (score 2):

I thought this might be useful

There are 3 places where the timezone might be set in MySQL:
Check here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-to-set-time-zone-of-mysql)